# Absolute Value of 2D Random Walk as Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Is the sum of the absolute values of the $X$ and $Y$ integer coordinates of a random walk in $R^2$ a Markov chain?

Ex. if the coordinates are ($X_n$, $Y_n$), and the probability of moving to any neighboring integer point is 1/4 (up, down, front, back). Is $Z_n$ = |$X_n$| + |$Y_n$| a Markov chain?

Comment: Consider (-2,0) and (1,1)... both have L1 norm of 2 but the probability of increasing L1 norm is 1/2 for second tuple and 3/4 for first tuple... so how could $Z_n$ obey the markov property?